# Cant Delete File Unless I Close My Program

Tags: c++, winapi

I have this code

```
CreateFileA(path.c_str(), GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_READ, nullptr, CREATE_ALWAYS, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, nullptr);
```

It works perfectly but the only problem is that I cant read, write, or delete the file unless I exit my program. Any Ideas?

Comment: Try switching to a different operating system, which allows it. Your operating system prohibits this, or does not implement it. The End.

Comment: Do you have the same problem with the core C++ functions to create files?

Comment: I think you should close the file because, while the file is opened by the application, you can't use it outside. Take a look at [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/closing-and-deleting-files)

Comment: @tadman No, only using CreateFileA

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I will try on my VM, thanks

Comment: Can't you simply close the file first?  Windows won't let you delete an open file.

Comment: @RobertoCiardi how do I close this file?, when I use other methods unix wise I dont need to do this

Comment: Yes, Unix is more forgiving.  See the answer just posted.

Comment: @PaulSanders sorry, I am new to windows specific programming, I am too use to unix. Thank you and everyone for their efforts.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should store the return value of `CreateFileA` in a variable of type `HANDLE`:

```
HANDLE hFile = CreateFileA(path.c_str(), GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_READ, nullptr, CREATE_ALWAYS, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, nullptr);
```

Then, when you're done with it, call:

```
CloseHandle(hFile);
```

After which you should be able to delete the file.

Comment: Thank you, this worked. I heard of std::filesystem in c++17. Do I need to do the same there if I create a file with it?

Comment: @GenZKaren I'm not to sure if `std::filesystem` can create files but I know it create directories. Such as `std::filesystem::create_directory` and no you do not need to assign anything to this. It will handle the calls on its own.

Comment: @GenZKaren `std::ostream` is the 'C++' way to create a file (and `std::istream` is the way to open one that already exists), and yes, you will need to close it before you can delete it either way.  It's a Windows thing.

Comment: @PaulSanders that sounds a lot easier to do, I will work with `std::ostream` from now on. Thanks for the help!

Comment: *"You Have To Assign A `HANDLE` Variable To The Function."* - None of that makes any sense. If you meant to say that you would need to assign the return value of the function to a variable, then even that is not strictly required, e.g. `CloseHandle(CreateFileA(...))` is perfectly valid.

Comment: @IInspectable it made sense to me, besides I call the `HANDLE`  for `GetFileInformationByHandle()` anyways before I close it so it wouldn't make sense to call the function twice.

Comment: @IInspectable I think we all know what he meant...  I will edit the answer.

Comment: @PaulSanders As explained, that statement is still wrong. The only requirement here is that you have to close handles you've acquired. Whether you store handle values in a variable or not isn't part of the solution.

Comment: @IInspectable Reworded.  Presumably the file is being opened for a reason, and needs to stay that way until the OP is done with it.  You're a bit grumpy today!

Comment: @PaulSanders Not sure why you attribute a keen interest in clear speech to grumpiness. The issue here is that a file handle isn't being closed. The solution is to close the file handle. Everything else is just noise (the majority of this proposed answer).

Comment: @PaulSanders `std::ostream` and `std::istream` do not create files. You meant `std::ofstream` and `std:::ifstream` instead

Comment: @RemyLebeau Ooops, sorry!

Comment: @IInspectable OK, tetchy then.